# Finding something in between characters

Tags: javascript

How can I get the word in between quotation marks and then replace it with something else from reading from a file

Note: I know how to read and write from files, I just need to know about getting the word from inside quotation marks

Comment: Do you know regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the word you're looking for:

```
let text = 'Sentence with "word" in it';
let wordFromFile = "nothing";
let newText = text.replace('"word"', wordFromFile);
```

Or else regular expression is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)*(regular expression)* with [regex replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```js
let str = 'How can I get the word in between "quotation marks"';
let word = str.replace(/.*"(.*?)".*/g,'$1');
let replacedWord = 'single quotes';
console.log(str.replace(word,replacedWord))
```

Comment: Why include `.*` at the beginning and end of the regex?

Comment: to say any chars arounding quotes would be deleted and let only the text inside the quotatoin as the OP asked

Comment: Oh, okay. Probably better just to `match` then, or do it all with just one `replace`.

Comment: Anyway, the use of the `g`  flag is incorrect as `word` would consist of multiple words if there is more than one pair of quotes in a multiline string, and the second `replace` makes only one replacement regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the word with a quotation mark for example `word` by `/"[^"]+"/` and replace it with other words for example `key`

```js
const str = 'This is the "word" which inside two quotation marks'

const result = str.replace(/"[^"]+"/g, 'key')

console.log(result)
```